# Custom Tootip not Shown full data

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, tooltip

I am using String builder to create tootlip in C# . but the value of tootlip is not shown full data how to rectify this problem i have mention the code below

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
var ErrorMessage = " unable to load data please try again " ;
sb.Append(" <i class='fas fa-info-square' data-placement='left' aria-hidden='true' data-toggle='tooltip' title='' data-original-title= " + ErrorMessage + " tooltip></i>");
```

Output :

> tooltip show unable only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have place your message inside quotas `'message'` so probably show only the first text.

Try this

```
sb.Append(" <i class='fas fa-info-square' data-placement='left' aria-hidden='true' data-toggle='tooltip' title='' data-original-title='" + ErrorMessage + "' tooltip></i>");
```

Note this part `'" + ErrorMessage + "'`